# What is the Deployment slot setting in Azure app server application settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What is the purpose of the `Deployment slot setting` in the Azure App Server | Configuration | New application setting?

[image]

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#which-settings-are-swapped)

Comment: Will explain in detail with an example.

Comment: The app settings which are selected as `Deployment Slot` are not swapped during the slot swapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#which-settings-are-swapped)

- During the swap, there will be changes in the configured application.
- Application/Connection settings will be affected.

> App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
>
> Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)

- Under `Settings` option, only the `Environment Variables`(Application and Connections String) settings has got an option to stop from swap.

This means that, to avoid changes/swap for a particular slot setting, we can configure it by using the option `Deployment slot setting`.

[image]

- Check mark the setting which you don`t want to swap.

***Check the below workaround to know more about the `Deployment slot setting` option.***

- The setting which you have not marked as `Deployment slot setting` can be seen in the process of swap.

***With uncheck option:***

[image]

[image]

- I have set the application Setting in Production slot and I have not checked the `Deployment slot setting` option, you can see that during Swap, the Production value is getting swapped with the staging slot.
- It means, the staging value will be set with the Appsetting and Production will loose the setting as staging doesn't have any app setting.

***With check option:***

[image]

- In this case I have set the app setting with `Deployment slot setting` option ( where I want to stick my settings to the particular slots). There will be no changes in the settings now.

[image]

- In short, To make an application/connection settings stick to the slot, we need to check the `Deployment slot setting` option.
- Mainly this option is used for Connection Strings, where we don't want to swap the production ConnectionString to Staging.