# When I did a swap of Azure app servers, the connection strings did not swap

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The settings are set to copy. The advanced edit shows:

```json
  {
    "name": "LouisHoweDb",
    "value": "Data Source=MyDomain.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;User ID=Me;Password=MyPassword",
    "type": "SQLAzure",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
```

These did copy over to the production slot. But aren't the production settings supposed to copy over to the dev slot?

Comment: Click  the "Slot setting" checkbox for that setting so it moves with the slot.

Comment: @Dai I thought is was don't check the box for the settings to swap. The box is not set in my case and it did copy dev => production.

Comment: Please refer my previous answer for your Post in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664044/what-is-the-deployment-slot-setting-in-azure-app-server-application-settings/77664649#77664649) which explains the functioning of Deployment Slot.

Comment: Please let me know if the above link is helpful or Are you looking for any more details ?

Comment: @Harshitha That other post is one I used previously to set this all up. What I don't understand is why didn't the production settings swap to dev? The dev settings swapped to production as expected, but I assumed the production settings would swap to dev. Or is that a one way copy, and no swap?

Comment: AFAIK, the production settings will get swapped to Dev and vice-versa with deployment slot option unchecked.

Comment: Will try to check from my end and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cloned the Dev Slot from the Production Slot, then all the configurations will be copied from the Production slot.

[image]

- Here I have selected `Do not clone settings` option.
- This option will create a new slot with name `Dev` within the same App Service Plan => App Service without copying any configurations from the Production.
- I have set connection string in Production and I don't have any settings in Dev Slot.
- Now Iam swapping the slots.
- With `"slotSetting": false` option the configuration from Production will be swapped to Dev and Production slot will lose the configurations.

***Configuration Changes:***

[image]

[image]

***Configurations after Swap:***
*Production:*
[image]

*Dev:*
[image]

Thanks @Dai for the comment.

The setting with `"slotSetting": true` will not copy configurations and there will be no change in the configuration settings.

> but I assumed the production settings would swap to dev. Or is that a one way copy, and no swap

The swapping of configurations depends completely on the `Deployment slot option`.

Comment: Thank you. And do you know where I can set `Deployment slot option` after I've created the slot? TIA

Comment: That is available for application and connection string settings.