# Azure slot swap - Do both slots have same "sticky settings" during warmup?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-deployment-slots

My understanding of Microsoft's documentation on [what happens during a swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#what-happens-during-a-swap), is that if there are slot specific settings, they are applied to the source slot and source is restarted.

If this is the case, does this mean that there is a brief moment where both source and target are running with the same target specific settings?

I have a C# application that reads messages from an Azure Service Bus and the connection to that resource is slot specific (I do not want my staging slot to ever consumer production messages). During the swap, it's possible both source and target will consume messages from my production Azure Service Bus, correct? Is it possible to get around this?

I tried creating a proof of concept to check for this but it's very difficult to understand what is happening to the settings during a swap.

Comment: which language you are using to read messages from sevice bus?

Comment: It's a .NET c# application.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: In C# you are using .net core web api or  .net MVC/core?

Comment: It's a .net core web api. I can't share the code but I don't think it's relevant either. My question is more about if this is actually the case and both source and target will have the same settings momentarily and if there is a general strategy to address this.

Comment: Refer this [SOAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664044/what-is-the-deployment-slot-setting-in-azure-app-server-application-settings/77664649#77664649) to understand the settings during slot swap.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not answer my question. I understand sticking settings to a deployment slot. The question is whether or not there will be a moment where both instances will be running with the same production slot settings and there could be unexpected behaviour due to it.

Comment: @BadAtMath, Can you add app setting WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_PRESERVE_DEFAULT_STICKY_SLOT_SETTINGS to every slot of the app and set its value to “0” or “false”.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `production` messages going into `staging` environment by giving the servicebus connection string seperately to staging and production environments in  `launchsettings.json` file.

To give the connection strings for the different environments in local like below:

```
// appsettings.production.json
{
  "AzureServiceBusConnectionString": "your_production_connection_string"
}
// appsettings.staging.json
{
  "AzureServiceBusConnectionString": "your_staging_connection_string"
}
```

- when swapping is doing add the app setting  `WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_PRESERVE_DEFAULT_STICKY_SLOT_SETTINGS` set to`0` or `false`. check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal)

In the `slot-specific settings configuration panel, locate the setting for the Azure Service Bus connection string. Enter the appropriate connection string for the destination slot`. make sure you have provide the correct connection string to prevent production messages from being consumed in the staging environment.

[image]

Plan slot swaps during periods of low traffic or scheduled maintenance windows to minimize the impact on users and reduce the likelihood of simultaneous execution of both slots.

Slot specific settings adding like below:

[image]

The production and staging environments should be specified separately in the local setup with a Service Bus connection string. Please refer to this [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60961168).